# Error Code: MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: firefox, video, browser, flash, plugins

I want to watch some videos available as links on [this page](http://static-pt-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tutorials70.htm#stub). I tried 3 updated web browsers and all of them give the error: `Error Code: MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`

MY three updated browsers are:

- Opera Version 44.0.2510.1218
- Chromium Version 57.0.2987.133
- Firefox 52.0.1

Chromium gives the following technical details:

> Technical details :
>   The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

I wonder how I can play the videos preferably without having to install flash player.

By the way, I'm on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2

Comment: idk what the issue is specifically, but they're not Flash, they're HTML5.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, looks like a technology named `Brightcove` is being used for videos, I'm not sure

Comment: @Tetsujin One of video elements is like this: `<video data-account="2649925992001" data-player="default" data-embed="default" data-application-id="" class="vjs-tech" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api" tabindex="-1" poster="https://httpscisco-a.akamaihd.net/2649925992001/2649925992001_4930210617001_4930195143001-vs.jpg?pubId=2649925992001&amp;videoId=4930195143001">
    </video>`